# use functions in a simplistic SELECT/WHERE clause

Tags: sql, function, select, syntax, where-clause

I can use this simple (no 'set' involved) syntax in SQL (MySQL, SQL Server, etc.):

```
SELECT 1+1;
SELECT RAND();
```

but I wont allow me to use this:

```
SELECT RAND() WHERE ( RAND() < 0.5 )
```

It has no interaction with a sql set but I think that the syntax is legal and this should be allowed

Ideas are welcome... ;)

Comment: What are you trying to do ?

if it is only getting a random value between 0 and 0.5 do this :

SELECT RAND() * 0.5;

Comment: exactly what you are seeing... just obtain a set from random values...

Answer (score 0):

your query does

`select rand()` - get random number from 0 to 1
and then filter it by

`where rand() < 0.5` - getting another random number from 0 to 1 and if it < 0.5 then return 1 row with prevoius number otherwise return 0 rows

if you want to get random number from 0 to 0.5, you should do `SELECT RAND() * 0.5`

**update**

```
;with cte as (
    select * from (select rand() as number) as a where number < 0.5
    union all
    select * from (select rand() as number) as a where number < 0.5
)
select * from cte
```

Comment: Yes... and that should gave me a set of values under 0.5 and break when a value is above 0.5... I think the problem is here... SQL dont know a under SQL-SET items count to iterate... I'm trying to obtain more data from a SQL Expert that already had passed through a similar situation... ;)

Comment: Ok... I get your idea with the UNION but that is not what i'm seeking ... any way that syntax does not work with mySQL... works with MSSQL... I think the WITH() statement... can you give me a clue here ?

Comment: if you give desired output it would be simpler to help you

Comment: Thanks for your patience Roman... What I want is to output a set of random numbers... with a random lenght... so if "SELECT rand() WHERE rand() < 0.5" worked would be just fine... but the sql set iterator is dependent on the underlying data... ;)